# How to increase space in XAMPP on windows 7?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, wordpress-theming

i wanted to add AVADA to the wordpress ID of mine but this approach was rejected with a notice that i do not have enough space to add there.

Answer (score 1):

I followed these steps and I got this problem of mine solved!

go to: XAMPP >> find "php.ini" >> open it in note pad editor >> find "php_max" >> set the value to 1024M (e.g. 1GB) >> find "upload_max" >> set the value to 1024M (e.g. 1GB) >> save it.
then, go to >> localhost >> your wordpress ID >> media >> add new >> there you may see the information- 'Maximum upload file size: 1 GB.'